HealthBar in Roblox Studio
Im develop game in Roblox Studio, but my HealthBar not working.
My code:
local text = game.StarterGui.HealthBar.Health.Bar
print("Script started")
---------------------------------------------------------
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    print("Player add")
    player.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(character)
        print("Character add")
        local healthText = character.Humanoid.Health
        local function updateHealth(healthText)
            text.Text = healthText
        end
        character.Humanoid:GetPropertyChangedSignal("Health"):Connect(function()
            updateHealth(healthText)
        end)
    end)
end)
---------------------------------------------------------
print("Script ended")


It was supposed to show the health level in numbers, but it doesn't show anything.
P.S: im speak English so-so.

There is a few things wrong with your script:

its looks to be a server sided script, GUI should be edited in a client sided script. read more about this here
you're editing the StarterGui instead of PlayerGui. the client just simply clones the version inside the StarterGui to the PlayerGui
i would also be better to use WaitForChild on the humanoid.
you updated it to a fixed version of character.Humanoid.Health

What i recommend doing is create a LocalScript inside the game.StarterGui.HealthBar.Health.Bar. inside this script i would put the following code:
-- // Services \\ --
local Players = game:GetService("Players");

-- // Variables \\ --
local Bar = script.Parent;
local client = Players.LocalPlayer;

-- // Events \\ --
client.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(Character)
   local Humanoid = Character:WaitForChild("Humanoid");

   Humanoid.HealthChanged:Connect(function(Health)
      Bar.Text = Health;
   end);
end);


Good answer, as a small note though, while WaitForChild is usually good practice, there's no need to use it inside CharacterAdded for the Humanoid. The docs say this : "Note that the Humanoid and its default body parts (head, torso, and limbs) will exist when this event fires, but clothing items like Hats, Shirts, and Pants may take a few seconds to be added to the character."

@Kylaaa thanks for your comment. i didnt know these values were already there. guess i've learned something today too!

Thanks for the help :) it turns out that it was necessary to make a handler via if)
